# Vertical space in table columns

Tags: tables, spacing, exam

I am creating following form. The table is meant to be filled manually using pen or pencil. But the space that becomes available in each line is limited (vertical). How can I increase vertical space in between the columns

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol, setspace}
    \usepackage{textcomp, booktabs,colortbl}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \setlength\columnsep{10pt}
    \onehalfspacing
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
    OPD ENCOUNTER FORM}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.1in}

    \makebox[\textwidth]{Name :\enspace\hrulefill}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Age:\enspace\hrulefill}
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Sex:\enspace\hrulefill}
    \end{multicols}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{Address:\enspace\hrulefill}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Dated: \enspace\hrulefill}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Ref: \enspace\hrulefill} 
    \end{multicols} 
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{Present Problem}
    \fillwithlines{0.5in}
    %----------------------------------------------------------

    \section*{\large \textrecipe}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{3cm}p{3cm}clc} 
    \toprule 
     Sr No & Drug & Dose  & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule
    1 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

     2 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

    3 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 

     4 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ 

    5 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \\

    6 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

    7 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`. Change `2` as you want for example `3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
    \usepackage{multicol, setspace}
    \usepackage{textcomp, booktabs,colortbl}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \setlength\columnsep{10pt}
    \onehalfspacing
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
    OPD ENCOUNTER FORM}}}
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.1in}

    \makebox[\textwidth]{Name :\enspace\hrulefill}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \vspace{0.2in}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Age:\enspace\hrulefill}
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Sex:\enspace\hrulefill}
    \end{multicols}
    \makebox[\textwidth]{Address:\enspace\hrulefill}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Dated: \enspace\hrulefill}
    \makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Ref: \enspace\hrulefill}
    \end{multicols}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    \section*{Present Problem}
    \fillwithlines{0.5in}
    %----------------------------------------------------------

    \section*{\large \textrecipe}
    \begin{table}[htp]
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{3cm}p{3cm}clc}
    \toprule
     Sr No & Drug & Dose  & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule
    1 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

     2 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

    3 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

     4 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

    5 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \\

    6 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\

    7 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to specify manually the skip you want after each row substituting `\\` with `\\[skip]`.

In this way you can even differentiate the skip for each row.

For example, in the following MWE, I've given `5ex` after each white row and `7ex` after each grey row:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol, setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp, booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\columnsep{10pt}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{5.5in}{\centering
OPD ENCOUNTER FORM}}}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.1in}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name :\enspace\hrulefill}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace{0.2in}
\makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Age:\enspace\hrulefill}
\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{Sex:\enspace\hrulefill}
\end{multicols}
\makebox[\textwidth]{Address:\enspace\hrulefill}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Dated: \enspace\hrulefill}
\makebox[0.45\textwidth]{Ref: \enspace\hrulefill}
\end{multicols}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\section*{Present Problem}
\fillwithlines{0.5in}
%----------------------------------------------------------

\section*{\large \textrecipe}
\begin{table}[htp]
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{c p{3cm}p{3cm}clc}
\toprule
 Sr No & Drug & Dose  & Frequency & Duration & Remark \\ \midrule
1 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[5ex]

 2 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[7ex]

3 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[5ex]

 4 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[7ex]

5 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night  \\[5ex]

6 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[7ex]

7 &  &  & -~~ -~~ -  & x & before/with/after meals, at night \\[5ex] \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]